# Is object oriented programming fundamentally different than imperative programming?

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented

I have been using C for a while, for some reasons I learnt C++.

I can't see why object oriented is a "new" feature. For me an object is just a structure, and a set of functions which have a pointer to this structure as a parameter(the this parameter). So instead of creating structures then functions that modify them, the compiler gives you a direct way to do it.
Also for Late Binding, I see it as the same as if you had a hidden member in the structure to a function pointer. So again, nothing new in itself.

So is OO just a compiler feature to make imperative easier by automating some things ?

Comment: I do not know why I cannot answer it. You can write procedural programming in Fortran and Object Oriented programming in C. C++ is OOP means that it readily supports Object Oriented concepts. You do not need any hack to support those encapsulations, abstraction, polymorphism. These are naturally supported by the language. OOP also enables to view the problem at much higher level as we see it in real life.

Comment: Advantage of OOPs are mentioned in the question listed here.